# Room LiveData not updating correctly

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have a room query that selects the orders submitted within the last hour. when I add/edit the orders everything works great.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM OrderTable WHERE datetime(delivery_date) > datetime('now','-1 hour','localtime') ORDER BY datetime(delivery_date) DESC")
fun getAllAvailable(): LiveData<List<Order>>
```

The problem is when I have some orders within the last hours and there is no edit/add in the orders table, orders don't disappear after their time passed the one-hour range!

Let me explain with a simple example:
There is an order with delivery_date of 2021-05-22 14:00, when the time of device is 2021-05-22 14:30 the livedata result show the order and it is okay, when time pass and it is 2021-05-22 15:01 it should remove the order from the result but it doesn't and always show the order until next add/edit occur to the order table and live data updates!!

P.S: I should mention that Room database instance is singleton using hilt.

Answer (score 0):

You are using query to fetch LiveData for last hour but it will not be executed unless there is a change in room database or your activity/fragment's lifecycle is resumed.

Refer this again : [Documentation for LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Here is simple sequence:

> 1. Database changes
> 2. Livedata updates the observers
> 3. Observers are executed

In your case, you are implementing the logic in your query, it does not know that it should be executed.

You can use a runnable to achieve what you want. Consider [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-run-a-method-every-10-seconds-in-android).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wonder if iivedata is not updated, why observers receive orders again and again (when I log it I see it receive continuously)? and is there any other way besides creating continuous update call?

Comment: @MohamadMohamadPoor Are observers continuously being called even when you are staying on same activity/fragment? Check with your logs if that is happening. But do not navigate to any other component while you are checking the log because observer will be called in that case.

Comment: Yes exactly, the observers receive the orders list again and again even I am in the same fragment and do nothing!

Comment: I will update you if I try this. Till then, if you want you can make a refresh button where you can fetch again. That is less costlier.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am trying to find out what's the problem too.